# Create dynamic object with unknown property types

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reflection, expandoobject, dynamicobject

I want to create a generic server-side DataTable solution on a ASP.NET MVC application. What I have on each `Index` view would be a JQuery datatable with a AJAX call to the controller to retrieve the paged data result. The operations performed are as follows:

```
public JsonResult GetNewRequests([ModelBinder(typeof(DataTablesModelBinder))] DataTablesPageRequest pageRequest)
{
    var page = RequestsQuery(pageRequest); // Retrieves page of result from db and does any filtering + sorting
    var pageResponse = DataTablesFormat.PageResponse(pageRequest, page); // Formats response for jQuery DataTable to use
    return Json(pageResponse, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); // Returns result
}
```

The response returned to the jQuery DataTable control is in the following format:

```
return new
{
    sEcho = pageRequest.Echo,
    iTotalRecords = report.TotalItems,
    iTotalDisplayRecords = report.TotalItems,
    sColumns = pageRequest.ColumnNames,
    aaData = results
};
```

The part I'm working on is formulating the list of model items to return ie:

```
aaData = results
```

`results` should be a list of any model object including all its relevant properties. I've been trying to use `reflection` together with `ExpandoObject` to complete this solution but cannot figure out the mechanics:

```
public static object PageResponse(DataTablesPageRequest pageRequest, Page<object> report)
{
    List<object> results = new List<object>();

    foreach(var item in report.Items)
    {
        dynamic dynamicObject = new ExpandoObject();
        Type type = item.GetType();
        PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();

        foreach(PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {
            Type propertyType = property.PropertyType;
            // Here is where I want to add a property with the correct name of the required type to the dynamic object
            dynamicObject[property.Name] = property.GetValue(item, null) as propertyType;
        }

        results.Add(dynamicObject);
    }

    return new
    {
        sEcho = pageRequest.Echo,
        iTotalRecords = report.TotalItems,
        iTotalDisplayRecords = report.TotalItems,
        sColumns = pageRequest.ColumnNames,
        aaData = results
    };
}
```

I've figured out a few things even while typing this. The part I cannot figure out:

```
dynamicObject[property.Name] = property.GetValue(item, null) as propertyType;
```

That is, setting property type eg: `DateTime`.

Let me repeat. I want to construct a list of model items. This can be any model type with any number of properties that each can be of any type (int, string, bool, DateTime, etc.)

Comment: You can use `Convert.ChangeType`. The question is why would you want to do that? You're already using `dynamic`, are you trying to have it passed in place of an interface or what?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast your expando to an `IDictionary<string, object>` if you want to be able to add properties dynamically:

```
foreach(var item in report.Items)
{
    dynamic dynamicObject = new ExpandoObject();
    var dic = dynamicObject as IDictionary<string, object>;
    var properties = item.GetType().GetProperties();

    foreach(PropertyInfo property in properties)
    {
        dic[property.Name] = property.GetValue(item, null);
    }

    // At this stage the dynamicObject will contain properties with correct
    // names and types

    results.Add(dynamicObject);
}
```

Comment: This seems to return an object in the following format: 
`[
    {"Key":"LogId","Value":1509},
    {"Key":"LogDate","Value":"\/Date(1428904824960)\/"},
 {"Key":"LogLevel","Value":"Information"},
 {"Key":"LogSource","Value":"EmailNotification"},
 {"Key":"LogText","Value":"Notification Process stopped"}
  ]` 

as apposed to the format: 
`[
    LogId:1509,
    LogDate:"\/Date(1428904824960)\/",
 LogLevel:"Information",
 LogSource:"EmailNotification",
 LogText:"Notification Process stopped"
  ]`

Comment: That is correct. That is how a dictionary is serialized into JSON.

Answer (score 1):

As Luaan already commented, `Convert.ChangeType` is the answer to your question.

However, using this won't help you any moment. Why? Since casting an object value will only help if you want to assign it to a variable of a specific type (opposed to `object`).

The underlying type of `property.GetValue(item, null)` will never change, so trying to cast it doesn't help.

Also, why not just use a `List<Dictionary<string, object>>` or even a `List<object[]>` (which I often use for data transfer purposes. There is no point in using `dynamic` or `ExpandoObject` here.